# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 Error 18456 Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, odbc

I'm trying to connect to our SQL Server box from our web server. The only thing i've been able to find regarding the issue is to enable tcp/ip and mixed authentication.

1. TCP/IP is already enabled
2. Mixed authentication mode is selected
3. we already have 1 user successfully connecting to a different database so I know TCP/IP and mixed authentication are working.
4. Logging in as the problem user from sql manager works fine.
5. I get the same error creating an ODBC connection as well as a ColdFusion SQL Server data source.

According to the log files, which isn't logging all the attempts also indicates State 40, which is "Default database could not be accessed (SQL 2008)."
I've check and the default database is the one I want to open. The Schema is DBO.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you are running this on a web server (not entirely sure how coldfusion runs, but know its web based). If so, you need to check what identity is being used by the service/app pool and make sure that it has the relevant permissions.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. Doesn't that just pertain to windows auth?  The Authentication is set to mixed with a sql server user name.  I am also able to connect successfully to one of the databases with a different user from the coldfusion box so that should confirm that I'm getting good communication, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you have a username and password specified in your connection string, it should use those using SQL authentication. If you don't, it will be using Windows Authentication - which will be the identity of whichever service is sending the request.

Comment: I just tried to connect to the DB as SA but that didn't work either. there is one user that can connect to the database but I can't find anything special about that user or DB that would allow it to connect where others can't.

Comment: Are you sure TCP/IP is enabled on the proper port, and that your CF datasource is configured for that port?

Comment: Hi Charlie, good to see you.  Yes, I promise TCP/IP is enabled on 1433.  There is 1 user configured to get through some how on a different database.  I think we can eliminate the CF server from the equation anyway.  I tried creating a UDL file ON the sql server box and the only connection that would work is the same one that works on the CF box. SA wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for not answering this sooner. To be honest I completely forgot about the question until I got a 'Notable Question' badge from it. Unfortunately, I'm afraid it won't help anyone as the problem was caused due to bad information from the network admins. They moved our SQL server to another box but did not shut down the old instance.  Essentially, they gave me the old IP to connect to.  Once I got the correct IP to the new box everything worked perfectly.  The user I thought was connecting was an older account that was already established prior to the 'move' so the account existed on the old box.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your user password not longer than 16 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If your box has multiple IP's on it, make sure the Cold Fusion server's IP address (that it's binded to) is allowed access to the SQL box.  I've come across this problem in the past.  I don't know if you're using a firewall or not to restrict access...but this was a problem I've encountered in the past.